# How to create packages of 10 elements for computing the mean of a value in Java 8.0 with Flink 1.9.1

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing, mapreduce, apache-flink

I have been working with Java 8.0, Flink 1.9.1 and Maeven 1.8.

To my hands arrived the following csv which collects the data from Taxi trips done in NY.
[image: dataset]
you can download it from here: https://dl.lsdupm.ovh/yellow_tripdata_2020-01.csv

To me the important variables are:

- Id - Column 0
- when the trip started - Column 1
- when the trip ended - Column 2
- distance driven - Column 4

The Id divides the two taxi agency that exist in the records. Agency 1 and Agency 2.

I wanted to compute the:

- mean in seconds of every 10 trips of each group ( 1 and 2 )
- mean of the distance of every 10 trips of each group ( 1 and 2 )

I want to obtain the following output:

- 2, 1.68, 5395 -> ( id, mean of the distance of ten trips , mean of the time driven in seconds )
- 2, 3.26, 752
- 1, 3.61, 897
- 2, 4.72, 1196
- etc...

The path I have follow to obtain that output is:

1. Parse the dataset as a string
2. Create new SingleOutputStreamOperator variable with a Map function. In where I cast the date( string ) to miliseconds in long with SingleDateFormat("").parse(). After,  I will substract when the trip finished in miliseconds from when the trip started also in milisecond. Returning a SingleOutputStreamOperator of three elements Id/distance driven / time in miliseconds
3. Cast that DataStream into KeyedStream using Keyby(0). 0 is the id, which will create two packages one with the id 1 and another with the id 2.
4. This is the part in which I'm stuck. I need to create pacakages of 10 trips
5. Compute the mean of distance and mean of time traveled for each of one of those 10 trips packages for id 1 and id 2. They can't be mixed.

Notes: I have tried to do it with Time Windows but I wasn't able to limit the packages to 10 trips.

Thank you very much for your help and time.

If you need something like code, please just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use count windows:

```java
stream
  .keyBy(t -> t.f0)
  .countWindow(10)
  .process(...)
```

There's also a nice [example in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#using-keyed-state) showing how to do exactly this from scratch (meaning, if count windows hadn't been included in the API).